# Match docs having all array element within $gte $lte

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here are my example documents:

```
{
updated: [
    1461062102,
    1461062316
],
name: "test1",
etc: "etc"
}

{
updated: [
    1460965492,
    1461060275
],
name: "test2",
etc: "etc"
}


{
updated: [
    1461084505
],
name: "test3",
etc: "etc"
}

{
updated: [
    1461060430
],
name: "test4",
etc: "etc"
}

{
updated: [
    1460965715,
    1461060998
],
name: "test5",
etc: "etc"
}
```

What is the correct usage of find query to fetch all documents matching updated date within `$gte` and `$lte` criteria?

for example

```
db.test.find({'updated':{$elemMatch:{$gte:1461013201,$lte:1461099599}}})
```

I can use $or and set it it like `updated.0:{$gte:1461013201,$lte:1461099599}`, `update.1:{$gte:1461013201,$lte:1461099599}` etc but what if my array will contain more updated dates?

As I understand $elemMatch doesnt' fit my criteria because it only matches the first occurence in array.

Comment: Have you tried with map reduce?

Comment: @bartektartanus `mapReduce` is the "poor and slow" cousin to the aggregation framework in just about all respects. It's main utility these days is for poor document structures where you have no other choice but to use JavaScript processing for element traversal. You just about always want things with native operators over JavaScript processing.

Comment: Unfortunately I know about "poor and slow" map reduce. But as you said - sometimes is the only option. Glad you find another with aggregate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. You were on the right track with [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), but this does take other logic not covered in standard operators.

So you either do with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/):

```js
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    'updated': { '$elemMatch':{ '$gte':1461013201, '$lte':1461099599 } }
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { 
        "$allElementsTrue": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$updated",
            "as": "upd",
            "in": {
              "$and": [
                { "$gte": [ "$$upd", 1461013201 ] },
                { "$lte": [ "$$upd", 1461099599 ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

Or in versions earlier than MongoDB 2.6, you handle with a [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) clause:

```js
db.test.find({
  'updated': { '$elemMatch':{ '$gte':1461013201, '$lte':1461099599 } },
  "$where": function() {
    return this.updated.filter(function(el) { 
      return el >= 1461013201 &&  el <= 1461099599;
    }).length == this.updated.length;
  }
})
```

The catch is that though a general native "query" operator can tell you that **one** array member meets the conditions, it cannot tell you that **all** of them do.

So the condition can either be tested with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$allElementsTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/), which are both available from MongoDB 2.6. With MongoDB 3.2 there is `$filter` and `$size` which are equivalent to the below JavaScript test.

Or alternately you use the JavaScript evaluation of [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) to test the "filtered" array length against the original and see that they are still the same.

That's the additional logic to build in to see that **all** match the range conditions supplied. The aggregate method is native code as opposed to JavaScript interpretation. It runs **much** faster by comparison.

But you still want to keep that [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) in all cases.

And of course, here are the matching documents:

```js
{
        "updated" : [
                1461062102,
                1461062316
        ],
        "name" : "test1",
        "etc" : "etc"
}
{
        "updated" : [
                1461084505
        ],
        "name" : "test3",
        "etc" : "etc"
}
{
        "updated" : [
                1461060430
        ],
        "name" : "test4",
        "etc" : "etc"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! It seems to be the correct way using aggregation framework. But as I test it, it gives an error: "exception: $allElementsTrue's argument must be an array"

Comment: @moogeek Are you copying "exactly" the code above? Which MongoDB version do you have? I'm running the exact code here using the data posted in your question, without any changes in either. The `$map` expression does return an array, so I'm guessing you actually changed something.

Comment: Yes, sorry I've not updated the my real key names used in production right. Now it works but shows no results.

Comment: @moogeek This is why you should **never** abstract questions when you ask here, since you inevitably miss details that are vital to the translation and then you don't know how to do that yourself. Look carefully at your real data and think about the changes you need to apply. If you cannot work it out, then it is best to [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the real details included this time. That way we can clearly see how it needs to be applied.

Comment: Thank you I understand that. Unfortunately my real data in each document is plenty big and may contain some confidential details which doesn't allow me to share here. I'll try to reproduce the issue and think out what goes wrong with the query